# Plot time series with confidence intervals in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a plot of several different time series that I made in R:[image]

I made these using a simple loop:

```
for(i in 1:ngroups){
  x[paste0("Group_",i)] = apply(x[,group == i],1,mean)
}

plot(x$Group_1,type="l",ylim=c(0,300))
for(i in 2:ngroups){
    lines(x[paste0("Group_",i)],col=i)
}
```

I also could have made this plot using `matplot`. Now, as you can see, each group is the mean of several other columns. What I would like to do is plot the series as in the plot above, but additionally show the range of the underlying data contributing to that mean. For example, the purple line would be bounded by a region shaded light purple. At any given time index, the purple region will extend from the lowest value in the purple group to the highest value (or, say, the 5 to 95 percentiles). Is there an elegant/clever way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your code, but have you looked at  `ggplot2::geom_smooth()`?

Comment: I believe that geom_smooth is for adding a mean -- it might be a good way of creating a version of my plot above, but I don't think it can be used to add an interval around the line.

Comment: I think `geom_smooth` is exactly what you are looking for, take a look at the last plot here: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_smooth.html

Comment: You need stat_summary to plot the CI. Here's enough information. http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_summary.html . You're interested in stat_sum_df("mean_cl_normal", geom = "smooth") but you could see that stat_summary can handle a lot of tasks

Comment: @MatiasAndina empirical quantiles are not the same as parametric confidence intervals, mean_cl_boot might be closer

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer using the `graphics` package (graphics that come with R). I also try to explain how it is that the `polygon` (which is used to generate the CI) is created. This can be repurposed to solve your problem, for which I do not have the exact data.

```
# Values for noise and CI size
s.e. <- 0.25 # standard error of noise
interval <- s.e.*qnorm(0.975) # standard error * 97.5% quantile

# Values for Fake Data
x <- 1:10 # x values
y <- (x-1)*0.5 + rnorm(length(x), mean=0, sd=s.e.) # generate y values

# Main Plot
ylim <- c(min(y)-interval, max(y)+interval) # account for CI when determining ylim
plot(x, y, type="l", lwd=2, ylim=ylim) # plot x and y

# Determine the x values that will go into CI
CI.x.top <- x # x values going forward
CI.x.bot <- rev(x) # x values backwards
CI.x <- c(CI.x.top, CI.x.bot) # polygons are drawn clockwise

# Determine the Y values for CI
CI.y.top <- y+interval # top of CI
CI.y.bot <- rev(y)-interval # bottom of CI, but rev Y!
CI.y <- c(CI.y.top,CI.y.bot) # forward, then backward

# Add a polygon for the CI
CI.col <- adjustcolor("blue",alpha.f=0.25) # Pick a pretty CI color
polygon(CI.x, CI.y, col=CI.col, border=NA) # draw the polygon

# Point out path of polygon
arrows(CI.x.top[1], CI.y.top[1]+0.1, CI.x.top[3], CI.y.top[3]+0.1)
arrows(CI.x.top[5], CI.y.top[5]+0.1, CI.x.top[7], CI.y.top[7]+0.1)

arrows(CI.x.bot[1], CI.y.bot[1]-0.1, CI.x.bot[3], CI.y.bot[3]-0.1)
arrows(CI.x.bot[6], CI.y.bot[6]-0.1, CI.x.bot[8], CI.y.bot[8]-0.1)

# Add legend to explain what the arrows are
legend("topleft", legend="Arrows indicate path\nfor drawing polygon", xjust=0.5, bty="n")
```

And here is the final result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have made a df using some random data.

Here's the df

```
df
   x         y
1  1 3.1667912
2  1 3.5301539
3  1 3.8497014
4  1 4.4494311
5  1 3.8306889
6  1 4.7681518
7  1 2.8516945
8  1 1.8350802
9  1 5.8163498
10 1 4.8589443
11 2 0.3419090
12 2 2.7940851
13 2 1.9688636
14 2 1.3475315
15 2 0.9316124
16 2 1.3208475
17 2 3.0367743
18 2 3.2340156
19 2 1.8188969
20 2 2.5050162
```

When you plot using stat_summary with mean_cl_normal and geom smooth

```
   ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point() +  
stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_normal, geom="smooth", colour="red")
```

[image]

As someone commented, maybe mean_cl_boot was better so I used it.

```
 ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point() +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, geom="smooth", colour="red")
```

[image]

They are indeed a little different. Also you could play with `confint` parameter depending on your need.